# How to analyze a large core dump generated when JVM crashes

Tags: java, coredump

My web application using Java one day crashed and generated a large core dump (5.5GB). I tried to use [IBM Thread and Monitor Dump Analyzer for Java](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/groups/service/html/communityview?communityUuid=2245aa39-fa5c-4475-b891-14c205f7333c) to analyze this core dump, but while reading the core dump, the console said:

```
Exception in thread "Thread-0" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Requested array size exceeds VM limit
at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:3332)
at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.expandCapacity(AbstractStringBuilder.java:137)
at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.ensureCapacityInternal(AbstractStringBuilder.java:121)
at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.append(AbstractStringBuilder.java:569)
at java.lang.StringBuffer.append(StringBuffer.java:369)
at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:370)
at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:389)
at com.ibm.jinwoo.thread.FileTask.processThreadDump(FileTask.java:1858)
at com.ibm.jinwoo.thread.FileTask$ActualTask.<init>(FileTask.java:215)
at com.ibm.jinwoo.thread.FileTask$1.construct(FileTask.java:1368)
at com.ibm.jinwoo.thread.ThreadHandler$1.run(ThreadHandler.java:31)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

It seems that the core file is too large to analyze with this tool. Increasing the heap size with the option `-Xmx10g` did not work.

What tool can be used to analyze such large core file?

---

Updated 2016-08-17 13:07:
I tried to use Eclipse MAT tool but I encountered an following error when I tried to read the dump file.

```
Error opening heap dump 'jvm-core.13074'. Check the error log for further details.
Error opening heap dump 'jvm-core.13074'. Check the error log for further details.
Not a HPROF heap dump (java.io.IOException)
Not a HPROF heap dump
```

Do I need to do kind of pre-processing or something to make the dump file readable to Eclipse MAT tool?

Comment: Based on the size of the file, this is probably either a heap dump file or a system core file; not a java core file (which is what the tool you used analyzes).
Look at the top lines of the file, a java core file is text and will start with something like:
0SECTION       TITLE subcomponent dump routine
NULL           ===============================
1TICHARSET     1252
1TISIGINFO     Dump Requested By User (00100000) Through com.ibm.jvm.Dump.JavaDump
1TIDATETIME    Date:                 2016/08/08 at 00:16:33

A heap dump would be a binary file (phd) that is much larger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that this core file is not for Java-related tools like Eclipse MAT tool or IBM Thread and Monitor Dump Analyzer for Java. The tools for the core file are `gdb` or `pmap`, `pstack`. I thought I can debug why application crashes JVM, but the core file seems to have little information about application-level things.

Answer (score 1):

I had great success with [Eclipse MAT tool](http://www.eclipse.org/mat/). You can also tweak its heap by changing **.ini** file in its installation folder as you would do in Eclipse. But make sure you have enough RAM available on your PC before loading a heap dump.

Comment: Thank you for answering. Unfortunately an error occurred when I tried to read the dump file with MAT. I edited the questions to include the error message from MAT so please check.

Comment: Was it IBM VM that crashed? WAS?

Comment: It was not IBM VM but OpenJDK.

Comment: What are the first 10 characters in the file if you open it (even if it is in a binary format)?

Comment: It's like this: `ELF>@@8�(Z�Q�@�`�Pe0`